# Sum of digit of a number using recursion in python

Tags: python, recursion, sum-of-digits

Here in this program, I tried to understand but couldn't get completely.
How is this recursive function doing the sum and returning total sum of this? Please explain me in detail?

```
# Recursive Python3 program to
# find sum of digits of a number
# Function to check sum of
# digit using recursion

def sum_of_digit( n ):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    return (n % 10 + sum_of_digit(n // 10))    # how this is working ?


num = 12345
result = sum_of_digit(num)
print("Sum of digits in",num,"is", result)
```

Comment: Sorry, no. You first. Please explain in detail each line of the code until you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand a recursive function is to dry run it.

First you need to understand what **n % 10** mean is. this means the remainder of a **n** when divided by **10**.
In this case when we divide **12345** by **10** , we get **5** as remainder.
so **n % 10** part of code becomes 5.

Now, the second part is **n//10** which gives you **1234** that are remaining digits.
Applying the same function again will give you **4 + sum_of_digit(123)** and so on.

Even if this do not clear your confusion try, running this code on paper with some small number.

Comment: My main objective was to ask about how this recursive function is adding?        
Please elaborate that part please!